# Python Selenium - How to upload image in this case?

Tags: python, selenium

Here is the HTML page:

```
<li data-picture-status="off">
    <p class="picture-uploader-add">Adicionar</p>
    <div class="picture-uploader-controls">
        <a role="button" class="ch-close ch-hide" href="#"><span class="ch-hide">Excluir</span></a>
    </div>
    <p class="picture-uploader-principal">Foto principal</p>
</li>
<div class="picture-uploader-controls">
    <a role="button" class="ch-close ch-hide" href="#"><span class="ch-hide">Excluir</span></a>
</div>
```

Here is my python code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(10)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//p[@class="picture-uploader add"]').send_keys('C:/image.jpg')
```

Here is the error:
`selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot focus element`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem that you're trying to handle wrong element... Try to handle `<input type="file">` instead:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="file"]').send_keys('C:/image.jpg')
```